# What is the equivalent of Java .get in python

Tags: java, python

I need to find the value of an element in an array in Python. In Java I would use `array.get(i)`. Is there an equivalent in Python?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion. I was using an ArrayList in Java, so I was using `array.get(i)`, and I forgot about `array[i]`

Comment: Did you try [googling](https://www.google.co.il/?ion=1&espv=2#q=get+item+by+index+array+python) it? I got over 2 milion results...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python you would do it exactly the same as in Java: `array[i]`.

BTW, Your `get(i)` is for `ArrayList` not for array in java.